# Maven Based Project With netbeans

Tags: web-services, jersey, maven-plugin

I'm starting with maven based project in netbeans. When trying to deploy my project (jersey webapp) I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file
>   (deploy-node-modules-artifact) on project SearchEngine: No transfer
>   protocol found.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Can you post the configuration of maven-deploy-plugin?